# List printing is not working as needed. Pattern made is 90 degree anti-clockwise

Tags: python, for-loop

So I want to print this list with many sub lists:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

y_coord = 0

for i in grid:
    print(*grid[:][y_coord])
    y_coord += 1
```

The expected output is:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

But the actual output is:

```
. O O . . .
O O O O . .
O O O O O .
. O O O O O
O O O O O .
O O O O . .
. O O . . .
. . . . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate the array to get the columns instead of rows as you are doing now. You can use `zip()` to transpose your array. Then just `join()` and print:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


for i in zip(*grid):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Prints:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Comment: I was literally 1 second too late, with the exact same answer ;)

Comment: So what does `zip` do?

Comment: @Naddy7706 it combines iterables together in a round robin fashion. Try `list(zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']))` to see it in action. It's well documented

Answer (score 1):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for x in range(0, len(grid[0])):
    print(*[y[x] for y in grid], sep='')
```

> Output

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But a little explanation would have been even better.

Comment: In the solution, nested loops are organized - the outer loop by x-coordinate and the inner loop by sublists (y). In one outer cycle, a list of all elements of the sublists with index x is formed and printed out as list values separated by an empty string `sep = '' `. Thus, the coordinates are rotated (transposition).

Comment: Wow nice! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show you how to fix the array, but don't explain what you're doing wrong. Let's take a look at your indexing expression

```
print(*grid[:][y_coord])
```

For python sequences, the index `[:]` generally means to make a copy of the container that points to the same data. For a list, like `grid`, it's equivalent to `list(grid)`. Notice that the nested lists are the same. So what you're really doing is the same as

```
print(*grid[y_coord])
```

Hopefully it's clear that this just prints the contents of the list line by line.

You can either pre-transpose the entire list as [@Mark suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67548536/2988730), or select elements from the correct column of each nested sublist as [@Алексей Р suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67548693/2988730).

Your original notation is evocative of numpy. If grid were a 2D numpy array, you could index it as `grid[:, y_coord]` to get the transpose. If you tried indexing a numpy array with the original double index, to you would get the same incorrect results for the same reason explained in the first paragraph.